# How do I stop an element from moving when the window resizes?

Tags: html, css

When I resize the window (drag the right side to the right), the green line will move to the right as well. In other words, it sticks out of the box. What do I do so that it stays inside the box regardless of resizing the window?

```css
.box {
  background-color: #000033;
  height: 500rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 18rem;
}

hr {
  color: green;
  min-width: 187.5rem;
  position: fixed;
  right: 55.5rem;
  top: 6rem;
  width: 18rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <hr>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the green line `<hr>` -  `right` is hiding that anyway

Comment: @Parham Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `right` property it will not move

```css
.box {
  background-color: #000033;
  height: 500rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 18rem;
}

hr {
  background: red;
  color: green;
  width: 187.5rem;
  position: fixed;
  /*right: 55.5rem;*/
  top: 6rem;
  width: 18rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<hr>
```

Comment: `left: 0; border-left: 0; border-right: 0;` to be all good

Comment: @Gad I doubt it - Thats not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following: https://jsfiddle.net/0vot7xrL/10/

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 18rem;
  height: 500rem;
  background-color: #000033;
  z-index: 0;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 6rem;
  left: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `hr` to:

```
hr {
  color: green;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 6rem;
  width: 18rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert `<link>` in `<head>` tag and remove second `</head>`.
2. Try writing width in **%** or `vw` and height in `vh` instead of `rem`.
3. Remove right margin and decrease value of **min-width** or better use `max-width` in `.hr` selector.

**Note:-** Instead of `rem` use **%** and `vw` for text, image and even in hr because it will help your webpage/website to become more responsive.

**Apply all the above points in your source code and your problem will be solved.**